# How to get all attributes of dom element using dojo

Tags: dojo, attr

Is there any way to get all attributes of dom element in DOJO (not specific one like domAttr.get("nodeId", "foo")).

```
<div style="border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius: 0px; height: 100px; background-color: #FFFFFF; -webkit-border-radius: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 900; width: 193px; left: 57px; top: 106px;" position="absolute" height="100px" width="193px" background-color="#FFFFFF" border-color="#000000" border-width="2px" z-index="900" -webkit-border-radius="0px" -moz-border-radius="0px" border-radius="0px" left="57px" top="106px"></div>
```

I want to read all attributes in div tag.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Dojo has a wrapper for this (I've done a brief search of the 1.8.3 source), but you can use [`Node.attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.attributes).

Dojo *does* use `Node.attributes` in places like [here in parser.js](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/1.8.3/parser.js#L222). Note the special handling of IE8 and IE6-7, to avoid falling foul of the same traps.